# Intel 82599 in CentOS 7 - No suitable device found for this connection

Tags: linux, networking, centos7, drivers, 10gige

I have recently installed a server with CentOS 7, this was installed whilst the network card was present. The card is a Intel 82599ES 10Gb LC fiber NIC attached to the PCI slot of the server.

The device does appear on the system:

```
#lspci | grep -i gigabit
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)

#dmesg | grep -i gigabit
[    1.247349] bnx2: QLogic bnx2 Gigabit Ethernet Driver v2.2.6 (January 29, 2014)
[    1.309813] ixgbe: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver - version 5.1.0-k-rh7.5
[    1.474375] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
```

However, when trying to bring the interface up with `ifup p1p1` I get the error:

```
Bringing up interface p1p1:  Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

After some reading it looked as though this was potentially due to a driver fault therefore I have download the latest driver from [the Intel website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/41282/Intel-82599ES-10-Gigabit-Ethernet-Controller), specifically the 5.3.7 Driver for Linux.

I then followed the guide on [Xmodulo](http://ask.xmodulo.com/compile-ixgbe-driver-centos-rhel-fedora.html) to install the driver on the system. After following all the steps and doing a reboot the issue remained the same.

As the next step I removed the `ifcfg-p1p1` file and ran `nmtui`. This has created a new file `ifcfg-Wired_connection_1`. However, when restarting the network service or trying to bring the interface up I am still getting the error:

```
#ifup Wired_connection_1
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

A few other bits of info that may be helpful

```
#lsmod | grep ixgbe
ixgbe                 314916  0
mdio                   13807  1 ixgbe
ptp                    19231  1 ixgbe
dca                    15130  1 ixgbe

#lspci | grep -i 82599
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)

#cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_GB.UTF-8

#uname -a
Linux test10g 3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 15 04:15:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#cat /sys/module/ixgbe/version
5.1.0-k-rh7.5

#cat /etc/*-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

I am not sure but I believe I may have had this working before with CentOS 6.5, but this was quite a while ago. At this point I am not sure how to proceed and any pointers would be much appreciated before i try 6.5.

**Update**

I have freshly installed the server (with the card present), with CentOS 6.5 and the card works straight away. I am still not sure how to resolve on CentOS 7 but this resolves my issue for the moment as the software is available under both versions.

Comment: During research I've found [Bug #1264024](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1264024) and CentOS [topic #57187](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57187). Can you provide a longer snippet from `dmesg` (since some important information is missing there)? Can you check if the NIC got an MAC address in log files? Can you also check and provide the Network Manager logs as mentioned in the CentOS Board thread?

Comment: @U880D I have just updated the question to include confirmation that CentOS 6.5 works without issue. However, I sure would like to know how to fix this for the future. I beleive I stumbled upon similar information regarding the MAC address and I can confirm that the `ifconfig` output showed a  MAC address. After I recreated the `ifcfg` file with `nmtui`, I ensured the MAC address was correct in the file, but the issue persisted. I will be reloaidng the server at some point so certainly once I can get back to that point I will post further dmesg logs. Many thanks for replying.

Answer (score 4):

Sometime because of unsupported SFP interface won't come up so solution is to create following file to allow unsupported SFP.

create file /etc/modprobe.d/ixgbe.conf

```
alias ens2f0 ixgbe
alias ens2f1 ixgbe
options ixgbe allow_unsupported_sfp=1
```

Do

```
rmmod ixgbe; modprobe ixgbe
```

add in /etc/default/grub file to fix the issue permanently

```
ixgbe.allow_unsupported_sfp=1
```